# Not all files are available after sync

Tags: sync, files

I have one folder set to sync automatically, and only a select number of the files are available via cloud. Also the files that are available have a green check-mark on them, whereas the ones that aren't available have a looping set of arrows (green and yellow) when I look back at the folder content. Any reason why all my files aren't available? Tkss

Answer (score 1):

Your files are still being uploaded to the server, the time it takes to complete the process depends on the total size of your files and your Internet speed. Here is what the emblems over the files mean [Sync status](https://edge.one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-file-sync/#Sync%20status)